# Supported API test error in WACK tools for windows 10 wup app

Tags: c#, api, windows-10-universal, wack

I developed WUP app after  testing WACK tools it given result Supported API test failed. with following message

•Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:◦API GetConsoleOutputCP in api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. NotNul.dll calls this API.
◦API GetStdHandle in api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. NotNul.dll calls this API.

I als got following warning in output

> C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(886,5): warning :           Unresolved P/Invoke method 'SetConsoleTextAttribute!api-ms-win-core-console-l2-1-0.dll' in assembly 'System.Console, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.
>   1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(886,5): warning :           Unresolved P/Invoke method 'GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo!api-ms-win-core-console-l2-1-0.dll' in assembly 'System.Console, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' because it is not available in UWP applications. Please either use an another API , or use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP application APIs.

How to resolve this issue.I am unable to find where i am using this api's in my code.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello Arun! I work on the .NET Native compiler team and would love to work on this issue with you. If you're still seeing this issue, Can you send cus a mail at dotnetnative@microsoft.com?

Comment: Thank you @MattWhilden  we resolved that issue initially we were using dotnetzip dll for ziping files now we migrated to .using new features in C#.

Comment: Glad to hear it. As I'm sure you'd agree, that error message is pretty unhelpful. Getting better error messages for stuff like this is something we've been investigating and I'll use this as an example when we're working through some of that.